# TSQL: Is there a faster or better way to encrypt values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, user-defined-functions

I have a masking/encryption function that loops through each character of a string and replaces it with a value from a table. Example of the table

```
Position    OriginalValue   MaskedValue
1           a               t
1           b               @
2           a               r
```

The function I have works for small sets, but really large tables take a long time. Is there a better way to write this function?

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SSNMask] (@string VARCHAR(100))  
  RETURNS VARCHAR(100) 
AS  

BEGIN 
DECLARE @Mask AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @Mask= ''

DECLARE @Char AS CHAR(1)
DECLARE @Counter AS INT=1
DECLARE @CharReplace AS CHAR(1)

WHILE @Counter <= (select len(@string))
BEGIN
    SET @Char=SUBSTRING(@string,@Counter,1)
    SELECT @CharReplace =maskedvalue FROM dbo.Mask WHERE Position=@Counter AND originalvalue=@Char

    SET @Mask=@Mask+ ISNULL(@CharReplace,@Char)

    SET @Counter=@Counter + 1
    SET @Char=NULL
    SET @CharReplace=NULL
END

RETURN (@Mask)

END
```

Comment: it should be faster with regular expression replace, so c# or python can do it better. if you can define CLR function, then you can use it in SQL server which would be faster.

Comment: CLR isn't an option in my environment.

Comment: You function is called SSNMask. You're implementing a [Ceasar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) to what end? It's reversable and might fool a 3 year old but is highly unlikely to protect the data from anyone with a modicum of intelligence

Comment: Why is the method inefficient? You are enumerating through each character in your `@string` parameter, potentially 100 characters. For each one of those, you're doing a lookup against your Mask table and then building a new string and returning that. You then perform that task for every row you pass in. If the supplied SSN was 111-11-1111 You'd be performing the same lookup 11 times and only ever generating 2 unique values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should scrap this method and instead look into using one of the several paired `ENCRYPTBY` / `DECRYPTBY` built-in functions:

- [ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186950.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYASYMKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189507.aspx)
- [ENCRYPTBYCERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188061.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYCERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178601.aspx)
- [ENCRYPTBYKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx)
- [ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910.aspx)

**EDIT:**
For situations that do not require decryption (i.e. a one-way transformation that cannot be transformed back into the original value), such as how passwords are typically handled, you can use the [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function, which can do the following algorithms:

SQL Server 2005 and newer can do:

- MD2
- MD4
- MD5
- SHA
- SHA1

SQL Server 2012 (and newer) added these:

- SHA2_256
- SHA2_512

---

All of the functions noted above (both `HASHBYTES` and `ENCRYPTBY_____` ) return a `VARBINARY`. If you need those hex digits in string format, the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function, starting in SQL Server 2008, added "style" numbers 1 and 2 to handle this:

```sql
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', N'test') AS [HashedValue]
)
SELECT cte.HashedValue, -- VARBINARY
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), cte.HashedValue) AS [DefaultOrStyle0], -- converted
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), cte.HashedValue, 1) AS [Style1], -- leading 0x
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), cte.HashedValue, 2) AS [Style2] -- no leading 0x
FROM   cte;
```